# Can't get the merchant to spawn

Tags: terraria

I got 50 silver coins for the first time but I didn't have a house prepared for him and this weird timer came up.

I went to my spawn just the guide in his house so a few days later I make a house for him get 50 silver coins no sign of him.

Do I have to make a new world? Should I just wait?

Comment: The merchant won't spawn until nighttime and when you are away from your house. Try walking away and wait until after night falls then go back and check.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to check:

- Use the housing query button and click on your house. Does it say the housing is valid?
- Make sure you have a house for both the guide and the merchant. The one you created for the merchant might be occupied by the guide, and the house intended for the guide might be invalid.
- Make sure your 50 silver coins are in your inventory, and not in a chest. You must be carrying the 50 silver for the merchant to spawn.

If all requirements are met, the merchant will eventually spawn during the day. You can be in your house when this happens, as he initially appears off-screen and walks towards the home built for him.

Comment: If you are playing with others, if you have 50 silver coins collective he will spawn.